# Merge C and D HDDs with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, backup, ssd, acronis-trueimage

Due to hardware issues, I would like to move my installation of Windows 7 as well as the rest of the installed programs and data from my C drive (a small SSD) to my current D drive, which would then become my new C drive. Ideally, without reinstalling everything, and without losing the data on the D drive. Technically, that doesn't seem terribly unreasonable to me, and I own Acronis True Image, if that helps.

Is there a way to do what I want to do ?

Comment: Create a backup image and restore to the storage device you want.

Comment: Won't that damage the data that is already there ?

Comment: Yes; of course it would but that's the only way to migrate the data from the ssd to the bed. You never indicate you wanted to save the data on the D drive

Comment: I edited my question to be more clear, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Do you have another drive you could temporarily store the contents of D drive?

Comment: Yes, I have extra storage to store both C and D at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to do that is:

1) Create backup of your D-drive (it will only work if it truly holds purely your data and doesn't have any applications installed )

2) Take an image with Acronis of the C drive

3) transfer the image to the D drive

4) Restore data from backup (D - drive) to a folder or folders on the new C drive

I have done this couple of times and it worked well

Comment: Thanks, this is what I went with, and it worked - D had a few applications installed, but a short registry search and edit was enough to get these to continue to work. Acronis even automatically extended the C partition while cloning it to the HDD.